# What's the difference between unset () and unlink ()?

Tags: php

I watch tutorial but i can't understand directly the discussion
can anyone help me?

Comment: I think you can find an answer more easy if you post this question on stackoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP unlink() is a function for file system handling, unlink() is used to delete files. Suppose you have uploaded a file and wants to delete this file through the coding then unlink() function is used to delete the file.

unset() is a function for variable management. It will make a variable undefined. Or we can say that unset() is used to null out the value of a given variable. OR Unset () is used to destroy a variable in PHP. In can be used to remove a single variable, multiple variables, or an element from an array.